# didUpdateToLocation not called with iOS 4 in my device...?

Tags: iphone, gps, cllocationmanager, ios4, didfailwitherror

I try lots and lots and searching most of posts, all with same answers. But I have take all the things included which is needed to use location service. My application properly get location and called *didUpdateToLocatioon* in simulator 5.1. But when I try same code with simulator 4.3, it gives me "**server did not accept client registration 68**". And when I try to debug the same code with my device with OS 4.3.5, it always go into *didFailWithError*.Can anyone have the same issue I had since last 2 days. And now I'm really frustrating with same answer from all around which I already did.

Answer (score 0):

It's just fault of device, with some issue I just switched off the device and now when I run my app in it, without a line of code change. It works fine.
After 3 day just wasting my time to posting and searching all.

So, my suggetion is if anyone who have the same issue like when u try to find location and it go into "didFailWithError".
Just restrart your device.